# Registration form has extra fieldset, where to find it?

Tags: templates, registration

I am working on a website, and I see at the user registration form another fieldset (custom one that i made) but I cannot seem to find it. Does anyone know where you can configure these fieldsets?

It's called jform_terms

Comment: Do you have custom fields and field groups defined for com_user?

Comment: I did, and all have a unpublished. But it seems that this is different, because it's a new fieldset. I think I set this in code somewhere, but I don't know where to put this.

Comment: You might have created a Template override and changed the form or default page in the override.

Comment: Nope, I changed the template to Protostar and it showed up. Weird, but doesn't anyone know where to add these fields? Seems weird to me that nobody knows that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It's called the [User - Terms and Conditions Plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Privacy#User_-_Terms_and_Condition)